# Install bitcoin core on raspberry pi 3

Tags: bitcoin-core, installation, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to install bitcoin core on raspberry pi 3 since I tried it once and it did not work out and I have an external drive for the bitcoin data for it?

OS: raspbian (8 GB space with 1TB HDD external drive)

If it does not work, can you explain it details to me why it cannot?

If it does work, can you tell me the correct way to install it?

Comment: https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/how-to-run-a-bitcoin-full-node-on-a-raspberry-pi-b/

Comment: https://www.alexanderjsingleton.com/running-lightning-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-raspiblitz/

Comment: https://www.raspberrypifullnode.com/

Answer (score 3):

It does work. Yes you need an external HD for the blockchain data (unless you want to run a pruned node) and Raspian is fine.

In my opinion the best tutorial for setting up a full node on RP3 is this:

[Damian Mee's Guide](https://medium.com/@meeDamian/bitcoin-full-node-on-rbp3-revised-88bb7c8ef1d1)

Comment: Hi @Britt - you may want to add some relevant detail from the site you mention since links tend to suffer from [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) rendering the linked information unusable.

Comment: It would be easier to ask OP why their install did not work when they tried to do it or where they got stuck. Otherwise I would just say install dependencies then git clone the latest version.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm just trying to help you get acquainted with how the site works.  Thanks for your answers though!